# Basic javascript code execution

Tags: javascript

Why does the x variable stays false even after multiple push on the button ?

```
<p id="text">Bonjour</p>
        <button type="button" id="button">Push to tranform</button>
        <script>
        var x=true;
        document.getElementById("button").onclick=
            function(){
            if ($x=true) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Au revoir";
                $x=false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Bonjour";
                $x=true;
            }
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: remove '$' from your code.

Comment: you're defining two different variables, $x and x, and using assignment instead of comparison in the `if` conditions.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your code:

- you don't define `$x` anywhere, you do define `x` but it's not used.
- Your `if` is bad: `if ($x=true)` should be `if ($x==true)` or even `if ($x===true)`.

`=` is assignment, whereas `==`/`===` is comparison/strict comparison.

The condition `$x = true` (which is an assignment) is *always* true so `$x` always becomes `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, you are **assigning** the value of TRUE, not **testing** it

```
if($x=true)
```

should be

```
if($x==true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the operator `=` (assignement) with `==` or `===` (comparison or strict comparison)

Moreover, you declare a variable `x` and use a variable `$x` not declared anywhere.

Finally when you test a booelan, you don't have to compare it to true or false, but you rather just test its value directly in the declaration of your condition. So prefer `if(x)` to `if(x===true)`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the x variable stays false

Because you've defined it as `x`, but you're setting `$x`.

`$x` is not the same as `x`. They are two different variable names; setting one and expecting the other to change is never going to work.

**Solution:** Remove the `$` signs from your variable name where you're using it.

Also `if ($x=true)` is wrong.

You need to use `==` (double equal) or `===` (tripple equal) to do a comparison. If you use a single equal sign, you are setting the variable (even in an `if()` statement).

**Solution:** Change the `=` into `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="text">Bonjour</p>
    <button type="button" id="button">Push to tranform</button>
    <script>
    var x=true;

document.getElementById("button").onclick=
            function(){
            if (x===true) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Au revoir";
                x=false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Bonjour";
                x=true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Needs `var $x = true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="text">Bonjour</p>
        <button type="button" id="button">Push to tranform</button>
        <script>
        var x=true;
        document.getElementById("button").onclick=
            function(){
            if (x==true) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Au revoir";
                x=false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Bonjour";
                x=true;
            }
        };
        </script>
```